# How to ignore duplicate values for UNIQUE field?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE my_table 
(
    my_column varchar(10) UNIQUE
);
```

I want to insert duplicate values. PostgreSQL throws an ERROR about  the UNIQUE column.

How to ignore the duplicate rows being inserted?

For example:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (my_column) 
VALUES ('cat'), ('dog'), ('cat') ;
```

I want to have table with this data after this statement:

```
cat
dog
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `on conflict`

```
INSERT INTO my_table (my_column) 
VALUES 
('cat'), ('dog'),('cat') 
on conflict do nothing;
```